# Kinetic-molecular model of an ideal gas, speed

Tags: thermodynamics

We make the statement that $v^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2  + v_z^2$ where $v$ is the speed of the particle.

This is equivalent to saying $v^2 = 3*v_x^2$.

But then we supposedly encounter the problem that when we substitute the latter expression into $P=(N/V) v_x^2$ to obtain $P=1/3 (N/V) v^2$, where P is pressure and the non-subscript V is volume;

We have made the assumption that they all have the same speed V, but this is incorrect??

Surely, this is fine as $v$ is the average speed of a particle in the 3D box we construct in the model, so even if the components of the speed in x y and z are not the same if we take the sum of the squares of them we should end up with a value that agrees with the same value calculated for other particles.